# Excel not showing time correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need help with times in excel 2010

I exported a list of mp3 durations, but the column shows minutes as hours.

For example, mp3 duration: 7 minutes and 30 seconds
in the csv exported files shows as 7:30:00

Plus, those mp3 with duration over 24 minutes, show also wrong
For example mp3 duration 27 minutes and 15 seconds
in the csv exported file shows as 01/01/1900 3:15:00

I would like them to show like this:

0:07:30

and

0:27:15

I have uploaded csv file if you want to take a look (42 KB)
http://www34.zippyshare.com/v/38064414/file.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution: add a helper column to the left of your time column. If your time column starts at C2 then just use this formula:

```
=$C2/60
```

This will convert the time to minutes seconds. Then just copy and paste as values.

Just drag this down your column. You may also need to change the number format of the column to hh:mm:ss as it will likely be displaying as hh:mm (hours and minutes)

**NOTE**
If you're using a table, you can reference the column name instead: if your time column was called Duration, and you add the helper column as a column within the table, the formula would be written like this:

```
=[@[Duration]]/60
```

Comment: But that converted 7:30 to 0:07...

Comment: In a way it does :D It converts it to 00:07:30, but Excel is still displaying the time as hours and minutes. Just go to the column's formatting options>number formatting. It will likely be set to the custom format hh:mm, just change it to the one underneath that; hh:mm:ss

Comment: You're welcome. Please sure to mark this as the answer if it worked for you. And welcome to SuperUser :)